# info indexing (within and without emacs)

Tags: linux, macos, unix, emacs

Does info provide any facility to link a `foo.info` file to info's main index?

The context is this: I would like to avoid maintaining my own index ("the info page for `foo.info` is in `/abc/def/foo.info`, ...").

The idea is to be able to type `info foo` and start reading the page, or, within emacs, to type `M-x info RET foo RET` and also start navigating.

Answer (score 5):

- For additional `*.info` files, that is, ones that don't come with Emacs, see the doc -- e.g. `(info) Emacs Info Variables` and `(info) Expert Info`.  Essentially, you just add an entry to the `dir` menu (the top-level, directory level of Info).
- Besides that, you can create virtual books with Info.

  - Vanilla Emacs gives you <kbd>I</kbd> (command `Info-virtual-index`), which creates a virtual index of nodes (across all manuals) that match a string you enter.
  - Better yet, [***Info+***](http://www.emacswiki.org/cgi-bin/wiki/InfoPlus) lets you add any Info nodes (pages) at all, from any manuals, to a virtual book.  You can have any number of such virtual books.  <kbd>.</kbd> (command `Info-save-current-node`) adds the current node, and <kbd>v</kbd> (command `Info-virtual-book`) visits a virtual book -- that is, a menu of saved nodes.

Comment: I see neither `(info) Emacs Info Variables` nor `(info) Expert Info` after doing `M-x info` and `m emacs`. What am I missing?

Comment: That's the standard syntax for info nodes. The word in parentheses indicates the manual (in this case 'info'), and the rest of the string is the node ('Expert Info'). So you can get to the first node via `C-h i info <ret> Expert Info <ret>`.

Comment: In `C-h i info <ret> Expert Info <ret>` the second `i` is already suspicious. Emacs attempts to input `i` in the info index file. Did you want to suggest `C-h i C-s info <ret> ...` or something similar?

Comment: Yes, `C-h i m info RET`. The point is to get to the Info manual.  Then use `g' to go to a node with the given name (completion is available) -- `g Expert Info RET`.