# info files in subdirectory is not recognized in emacs

Tags: emacs, info

I installed an additional info file using

```
install-info /usr/share/info/asymptote/asymptote.info.gz /usr/share/info/dir
```

it is perfectly visible by `info` command from the command line, i.e. `info asymptote` return content of asymptote/asymptote.info.gz properly. Also it is visible by emacs in the top node when I use `M-x info` command, but when I try to go to `asymptote` node, it complains "Info-find-file: Info file asymptote does not exist". The problem looks similar to [info indexing (within and without emacs)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8122214/info-indexing-within-and-without-emacs) although it is not quite the same. It seems that info command in emacs does not recognize the subdirectory, while the original `info` command does. Is it possible to force emacs behave in the same way?

Answer (score 1):

My understanding is that the main directory listing for `M-x info` is built from `dir` files found under directories in the `Info-directory-list` variable, and that same variable is used when searching for a named info file; so this is slightly odd.

You should verify that `Info-suffix-list` contains an entry for `.info.gz`, but that should be pretty standard, so my best guess is that the `dir` entry added by `install-info` is not quite correct (or not supported, at any rate).

Could you show us what the entry for asymptote looks like in `/usr/share/info/dir`?

Comment: `Info-*` variables in emacs look good, and the entry for asymptote in `/usr/share/info/dir` look like 
`* asymptote: (asymptote).       Vector graphics language.`
basically it points to the directory containing file `asymptote.info.gz`